# Generate white noise with amplitude between [-1 1] with Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, noise

I'm using the Matlab function `Y = WGN(M,N,P)` to generate white noise with Gaussian distribution.  This function uses a power value (dB Watts) to calculate the amplitude of the output signal. Since I want to get an output amplitude range of -1 V to 1 V there is a function mode 'linear'.

I'm trying to use the 'linear' mode to produce the output but the result is an output amplitude range of [-4 4]

```
RandomSignal = wgn(10000,1,1,1,'linear');
Time = linspace(0,10,10000);
figure()
plot(Time,RandomSignal)

figure()
hist(RandomSignal,100)
```

Is there another function to produce this result, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Gaussian distribution has tails to infinity; you can't guarantee that it will be limited to any particular numerical range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you can't limit a Gaussian distribution. 
What you can do is define your range to be 6 standard deviations, and then use randn(m,sigma) to generate your signal.

For example if you want a range of [-1 1] you will choose sigma=2/6=0.333 and Mu=0. This will create a chance of 99.7% to be inside the range. You can then round up and down those numbers that are out of the range.

This will not be a pure Gaussian distribution, but this is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 4):

why you just take randn function of whatever bound and then just normalize it like this ex.

```
 noise=randn(400); noise=noise./max(max(noise));
```

so whatever is the output of randn finally you will have a w.n. inside [-1 1].

Answer (score 3):

Gaussian noise has an unbounded range.  (The support of the Gaussian pdf is infinite.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rand` rather than Gaussian generator. The output range of `rand` is 0-1, so to make it in the range -1 1 you use `rand(args)*2 -1`.

It should be noted that this generator is sampling a uniform density.

Comment: Indeed, but then it isn't Gaussian.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Of course not. You can't have both. But he will still obtain a flat spectral density

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to say something very wrong, but when I copied your code and changed

```
RandomSignal = .25*wgn(10000,1,1,1,'linear');
```

it was then ok. Hope it works for you.(Assuming random data/4 is still random data)

Comment: It's not ok.  Reducing the noise power reduces the chance of getting values outside `[-1:1]` but the probability is still non-zero.

Comment: If you try this code several times will see some output amplitude fluctuations. Probably the WGN function is difficult to control so i'm asking for a mode that guarantee the output between -1 and 1.

Comment: @PVaz: If the noise is restricted to that range, it isn't Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

hello I think it is so late to answer this question but I think it can be useful for other research.
the function which is shown below is worked for producing gaussian random noise between [-1,1].

```
function nois=randn_fun_Q(S_Q)
% S_Q a represents the number of rows of the noise vector. For example, in 
% system identification, it shows the number of rows of the covariance matrix.
i=0;
nois=[];
for j=1:S_Q
    while i~=1
        nois_n=randn;
        if nois_n<1 && nois_n>-1
            nois_=nois_n;
            i=1;
        else
            continue
        end
    end
    nois=[nois;nois_];
    i=0;
end
end
```

you should use this function in "for" loop in main cod to produce n number of noisy point in range of [-1,1].