# generate white noise in matlab interval [-1 1]

Tags: matlab, spectral

I would like  to create or generate white noise in the range of [-1 1], but I don't know exactly how to do it. My programming language of choice is matlab. As far as I know there exists a function named `randn` and also a function named `wgn` (white gaussian  noise). So please help me with this issue, to clarify, for example I want to generate following equation:

```
x(t)=20*sin(2*pi*f1*t)+30*cos(2*pi*f2*t)+A3*white noise
```

where `A3=amplitude`  and  white  noise is in the range   [-1 1]. Please help me and clarify  how to do it. My  confusion is  related to  white noise, not about the others, let's assume that t is changing from 1 to 100.

Comment: This question is already solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527915/generate-white-noise-with-amplitude-between-1-1-whith-matlab

Comment: but for which part?how can i use  in formula?which function for  white nois egeneration?

Comment: There a difference between "white noise" and "white gaussian noise" ... See my answer for white noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

white noise  is a random signal with a **flat** (constant) power spectral density. for that you can use [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html). In order to obtain white noise in the interval [-1 1] you can just add to your expression `white_noise=(rand(1,t)*2-1)` .

Comment: do it  need index like white_noise(t)=(rand(1,t)*2-1

Comment: also  i should multiply   A3 by  white noise  simply when t is changing or  A3*white_noise(t)? please help me to clarify it

Comment: but i have tested and  maybe in rand(1,t) is not correct right?please answer me

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, but as natan says, you should be able to generate white noise from a uniform distribution of random samples.

I would proceed as follows:

```
wn = unifrnd(-seed,seed,[m,n])/seed;
```

Comment: Uniform distribution does not result in Gaussian white noise